# Can Windows 10 firewall be configured to interactively ask permission for outgoing traffic?

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall, traffic-filtering, interactive

I'm rather unfamiliar with the default firewall in Windows 10 Professional. I find many articles on how to configure or finetune it to filter specific traffic (ingoing or outgoing).

However what I would like is:

1. Allow certain apps to connect
2. Prevent certain other apps from connecting
3. When a new application tries to make an outgoing connection, Windows Firewall **should show a popup asking me whether to allow or deny it.** And preferably with an option to do so just once or permanently. Or perhaps even only allow the app to connect to specific addresses or servers, and deny others.

The 'interactive ask permission on the fly' feature is essential.

Is this possible at all with the Windows 10 Professional built-in firewall? Or would I need a 3rd party solution for this?

Comment: This should already happen.  Whenever an application gets updates on my personal machine, and it's connecting to the internet for the first time, I get a prompt asking for  an allow rule to be created for it.

Comment: No but this software enables this, after install be sure to turn on Notifications and set notification timeout to 999, then turn on Medium filtering profile.This is a front end for the Windows firewall >>>>https://binisoft.org/wfc

Comment: @Ramhound Would you know what settings or changes you made in your firewall configuration to enable this behavior? It surely doesn't happen automatically by default. I have experimented with it for a while but I can't get it to work. I can change the default policy for outgoing traffic for my network interface from Allow to Block, and that does indeed block outgoing traffic for apps that don't have rules yet. But whether I enable 'notify me' option or not, it never notifies me.

Comment: @Moab Never heard of that one before, but looks useful. Will experiment with that, thanks!

Comment: Its been around a while, then they teamed up with Malware Bytes and made the full version free, its on all my W7 and up PC's, can't live without it.

Comment: I can't get the notifications to work either. Using Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks @Moab I was able to set it up and have notifications.